In IIS 10, How to add an http response header at the application level but inherit it's value from the site level?
I deleted an inherited HTTP Response header in an IIS 10 application.  I would like it back, but inherited from the site level.
It seems that the application has marked the header at at the app level to be deleted forever.  I just want to allow the header to exist again and inherit it's value.  Is there any way to enter the header and force its value to be inherited?
Things I've tried:
Adding the header with a value of ""
Renaming and deleting the header at the site level
Googled and used AI to search

Figured it out.  In the web.config it simply has an entry for "removed headers".  I deleted that and the issue disappeared.
It is still astonishing that IIS doesn't allow you to know this from IIS manager...don't this people get paid enough?

IIS manager will allow you to make this change via the "Configuration Editor" when your at the appropriate level of the tree. But personally id just edit web.config for any app level config change. IIS mgr shows a composite view of the files in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\Config, plus any web.config files in the webroot and any sub folders. Also bare in mind IISmgr is a bit clunky, but it literally still supports technologies from the dark ages (circa 1996) so you have to curb your expectations of the GUI/ease of use. If you need any IIS level config, powershell/DSL/Ansible are all good options

This is kind of a well known issue for more than 15 years. The XML schema was well defined, https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/iis-7-and-iis-8-configuration-reference#collection-schema, but IIS Manager as GUI cannot give you all possible ways to configure the elements, especially when you have a <clear /> or <remove /> element in a collection. Experienced IIS administrators know when to resore to the configuration files instead of IIS Manager, as they know the limitation very well.
